# How to remove minutes from a time if they are zero (09:00 to 9am)

Tags: php, datetime, time

I need to convert 4 digit times to am/pm and can do that using this function: date("g:ia",$starttime) which converts 08:30 to "8:30am".

But I want times that are on the hour to hide the zero minutes. So I want 09:00 to be displayed as "9am". Is there something built into php to easily do this?

Comment: Just take out the `i` from your `date()` call. `date("ga", $starttime)`, you can check if "minutes" is 0 by `if(date("i", $starttime) > 0)
`

Comment: only for round hours you want this:like for 9am, how about 9:15 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```php
$date = date("g:ia",$starttime);
$date = str_replace(":00", "", $date);
```

Comment: Actually this is a pretty good solution, don't even have to check if the time is flat

Comment: Way to go people... Upvote an answer without proper formatting and no explanation or anything. @Auft... You should always explain what your code does so that the asked understands what the code does. Otherwise it will just be a copy paste and no learning. Generally it's better to focus on the actual description of the answer, that way the asked learns more.